# Rails - Float precision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, floating-point, migration

I have a float attribute, and I'm having problems with the precision. If save a value like "745.34", it saves correctly to database. However, if I try to save 4564523.845, for instance, it saves 4564520.0. Guess it's not a number that big that float doesn't suppor it. Some example of my console:

```
c.valor_total = 4564523.845
 => 4564523.845 
2.3.1 :034 > c.save
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  UnidadeConsumidora Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `unidade_consumidoras`.* FROM `unidade_consumidoras` WHERE `unidade_consumidoras`.`id` = 28 LIMIT 1
  SQL (21.2ms)  UPDATE `contas` SET `valor_total` = 4564523.845, `updated_at` = '2016-10-20 17:28:20' WHERE `contas`.`id` = 28
   (70.4ms)  COMMIT
 => true 
2.3.1 :035 > c = Conta.find 28
  Conta Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  `contas`.* FROM `contas` WHERE `contas`.`id` = 28 LIMIT 1
 => #<Conta id: 28, unidade_consumidora_id: 28, razao_social: "DROGARIA ARAUJO S A", ano: 2016, mes: 8, numero_cliente: "7000042467", cnpj: "17.256.512/0001-16", consumo_kwh: "10942", vencimento: "2016-10-18", valor_total: 4564520.0, created_at: "2016-10-19 18:43:35", updated_at: "2016-10-20 17:28:20", pdf_conta: "ADOLPHO_COTTA.pdf", unidade_de_leitura: "07020129", cod_instalacao: "3000728720", logradouro: "PCA ALEXANDRE LANZA 141 CO .", bairro: "CENTRO", cep: "35700-040", municipio: "SETE LAGOAS", uf: "MG"> 
2.3.1 :036 > c.valor_total
 => 4564520.0
```

See that on update sql log the value is correct... so what can it be and how I fix it?

EDIT:

schema.rb for contas:

```
  create_table "contas", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer  "unidade_consumidora_id"
    t.string   "razao_social"
    t.integer  "ano"
    t.integer  "mes"
    t.string   "numero_cliente"
    t.string   "cnpj"
    t.string   "consumo_kwh"
    t.date     "vencimento"
    t.float    "valor_total",            limit: 24
    t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
    t.string   "pdf_conta"
    t.string   "unidade_de_leitura"
    t.string   "cod_instalacao"
    t.string   "logradouro"
    t.string   "bairro"
    t.string   "cep"
    t.string   "municipio"
    t.string   "uf"
    t.index ["unidade_consumidora_id"], name: "index_contas_on_unidade_consumidora_id", using: :btree
  end
```

Comment: do you mind posting your SQL definition for `contas` table ?, or at least the important part where `valor_total` is defined.

Comment: @fanta post an edit with schema.rb... see if it helps! Thanks

Comment: Andrey gave you the answer, you need to include `precision` and `scale` in your definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure you just have the "wrong" database type there.

`Conta.columns_hash['valor_total'].type` would most likely return `"integer"`, whereas what you want to have is `decimal` if your goal is to store precise numbers.

I'd recommend to change the datatype:

```
change_column :contas, :valor_total, :decimal, precision: 5, scale: 2
```

## EDIT

You have used `float` datatype, but did not specify the precision. Even though you probably (never saw a `float` db type used) could change it and specify it, I would still recommend to use `decimal` for such things, because it does not do any round up or so while calculations, so you will always have the most precise numbers you can get.

Comment: That was exactly what happened! Worked like a charm... thanks so much!

Comment: @RonanLopes also, make sure to check what presicion and scale do, to pick the right ones for yourself

Comment: Did that, 15 on precision works fine for me. Thanks!